# Tiny Epic Galaxies - Can you follow and use ANY action?

Tags: tiny-epic-galaxies

There are some planets whose actions have come up as questionable whether they are allowed to be used by a player when it is not their turn (in a follow action):

**"...during your turn"**

Planet CLJ-0517

> "Steal 1 culture from another player (only once during your turn)"

Planet NIBIRU

> "Enemies must now pay 2 culture per follow this turn (only during your turn)"

Planet BISSCHOP

> "On your turn after utilizing this colony, if you are followed then acquire 1 energy per follow."

These seem to explicitly state that these actions can only be used during/on your turn. OR...are the effects of the actions held and come into effect when you take your next turn? Notice one of them is worded differently, outside of the parentheses.

**"...once per turn"**

Planet ZAVODNICK

> "Perform any 1 action; all other players may follow that action for free. (Only once per turn.)

Can a following player use it and if they use it first, no one else may? Notice an earlier card also has "only once" in the action.

**Dice Manipulation**

Planet ZALAX

> "Reroll any number of inactive dice"

Planet GYORE

> "Set 1 inactive die to a face of your choice."

These 2 are usually met with, "wait you shouldn't be able to use that to change MY dice." So I feel that we have homebrewed this rule to make it less cutthroat. Are these allowed as follow actions?

Comment: Why the house rules tag? Your question doesn’t mention any.

Comment: Sorry, was looking for a tag specific to rules. And the bit at the end, felt like house rules before we knew there were official further explanations on the dice manipulation cards.

Comment: No problem - just wanted to make sure I wasn’t missing something!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other players follow the die’s action - the action whose icon is showing on the die - not the specific action you take (where you move, the ability you use etc) when using it.

So when following a “Utilise Colony” die, the following player can use a Colony Ability only as if they had activated their own Utilise Colony die. This means they would normally only be able to activate the abilities of their own playmat, or planets they have colonised themselves. The exception is if they have a special ability that allows them to use other players’ colonies.

Likewise you can follow the “Move” action to land on a planet and use its ability, but only following the normal movement rules.

If a planet specifies it can only be used “on your turn”, then it cannot be used by following another player’s die, as this doesn’t happen on your turn. Abilities are resolved when you use them, so there’s no way to activate one and then have the benefits of it on a later turn.

In the case of Zavodnik, yes, it can only be used once per turn, even if it’s used by someone other than the current player.

The dice manipulation abilities can only affect your own dice, because - as per the clarifications of abilities printed in the lid of the box - they are also usable only on your turn.

These questions are all covered in more detail in [the rules FAQ posted on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Tiny_Epic_Galaxies_FAQ), which is drawn from official designer answers in the forums there.

Answer (score 2):

When following another player you follow the die, not the action.

When following a Colony action die you can perform any action on your own playmat, or any planets you have already colonized, except actions that specify they can only be used "on your turn".

Actions that specify they can only be performed on your turn can also only be activated on your turn, meaning they cannot be used as a follow action.

This allows for a following player to activate ZAVODNICK, and subsequently all other players to follow that action for free.
The limitation is that ZAVODNICK can only be activated once per turn regardless of who activated it first.
This is is detailed in a response from the [designer on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1625201/article/23502850#23502850).

For the dice manipulation abilities, there is a clarification of their rules printed on the inside of the bottom of the box, which limits their use to "on your turn". meaning you are unable to change other player's dice.
[image: TEG rules clarification]